# Clarifying the way in counting number of weeks for calculating historical weekly volatility in Bloomberg

Tags: volatility, bloomberg, excel

I would like to confirm the way to counting number of weeks for calculating historical weekly volatility in Bloomberg. Given an option with issue date from 14/1/2014 to 13/1/2019, is the proper way to count the number of week by using excel function,

ROUNDUP((13/1/2019 - 14/1/2014)/7,0)+1

for the purpose of calculating historical volatility based on term-matching principle. Is there any reference to describe the way to count the number of weeks for the purpose of calculating historical volatility based on term-matching principle?

Thanks.